# 22.04 Samba with AD user - cannot access from Windows

Tags: samba, 22.04, active-directory, kerberos, sssd

Fresh 22.04 install.  Only other configuration is NFS (which is working).  Directories are 777.  Configuration files:

**sssd.conf**

```
[sssd]
domains = home.net
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/home.net]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = home.net
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
ad_domain = home.net
use_fully_qualified_names = False
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad
```

**smb.conf**

```
[global]
   kerberos method = secrets and keytab
   realm = HOME.NET
   workgroup = HOME
   security = ads
   template shell = /bin/bash
   winbind enum groups = Yes
   winbind enum users = Yes
   winbind separator = +
   idmap config * : rangesize = 1000000
   idmap config * : range = 1000000-19999999
   idmap config * : backend = autorid
   unix charset = UTF-8
   server string = %h Naples File Server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   server role = member server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[test]
    comment = Test share
    path = /mnt/test
    read only = no
    force group = +video-access
    directory mask = 0775
    force directory mode = 0775
    create mask = 0775
    force create mode = 0775
```

**krb5.conf**

```
[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    renew_lifetime = 7d
    forwardable = true
    rdns = false
    default_realm = HOME.NET
    default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
    pkinit_anchors = FILE:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

[realms]
        HOME.NET = {
                kdc = 192.168.102.253
                admin_server = 192.168.102.253
        }

[domain_realm]
          .home.net = HOME.NET
          home.net = HOME.NET

[plugins]
          localauth = {
                   module = winbind:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/krb5/winbind_krb5_locator.so
                   enable_only = winbind
          }
```

**id user@home.net**  - successfully lists AD group and local group membership
**wbinfo -u** - successfully lists all AD users
Using AD DNS with static host name.
Server successful added to AD.  Realm reports it's joined
Directory permissions set to 777

Everything looks fine, however I cannot get past a login prompt on the Win10 client when attempting to access the share.  I've even turned on SMBv1.

Have been working on this for too long to admit.  Am spinning my wheels. Can anyone please help?  This configuration was working on 20.04 for years.

Thanks